# Как в jQuery.data() добавить параметры $this?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, count, счетчики

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь создать счетчики отдельно для каждого товара, которые должны обновлять  цену, при наступлении соответствующего события, но проблема в том, что у меня не получается сохранить базовую стоимость и счетчик работает по принципу прогрессии. Пытаюсь сохранять через метод `jQuery.data()`, но в консоли пишет ошибку `undefined`, т.к. функция не умеет работать с `this` ?

```js
function numberWithCommas2(n) {
 var parts=n.toString().split(".");
 return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
function parseNumber2(str) {
 var regExp = /\d+/g;
 var part;
 var result = 0;
 while (part = regExp.exec(str)) {
  result = result * Math.pow(10, part[0].length) + parseInt(part[0]);
 }
 return result;
}
 $('.product-quantity .input-text.qty.text').change(function() {
   var quantity = $(this).val();
   var $this = $(this).parents('.product-frame ').find('.amount');
   var input_amount = parseNumber2($this.text());
   $.data($this, 'baseprice', input_amount);
   console.log( $this.data('baseprice') );
   var total = quantity * input_amount;
   $this.text(numberWithCommas2(total) + " руб.");
 });
```

```html
<div class="product-frame">
  <div class="product-section">
    <table class="description-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="product-quantity">
            <div class="quantity buttons_added">
              <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
              <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
              <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не правильно используете, смотрите как нужно:

```
$(domElement).data('someKey',somedata);
```

в вашем случае:

```
$this.data("baseprice", input_amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно - решил с помощью `attr` и условия:

```
    $('.main-product .product-quantity .input-text.qty.text').change(function () {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var $this = $(this).parents('.product-frame ').find('.amount');
    if($this.attr('baseprice'))
    {
        var input_amount = $this.attr('baseprice');
        var total = quantity * input_amount;
        $this.text(numberWithCommas2(total) + " руб.");
    }
    else {
            var input_amount = parseNumber2($this.text());
            $this.attr("baseprice", input_amount)
            var total = quantity * input_amount;
            $this.text(numberWithCommas2(total) + " руб.");
    }

});
```